# Replace using ifelse not reduce length of vector in R?

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to create a new column `new.val` based on unqiue cut-off values for each level and val. If, level = `high` and val > 35 then new.val is 0. If, level = `low` and val > 30 then new.val is 0.

I tried using an ifelse condition and I get the error `Error in` $<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, new.val, value = c(0, 0, 0)) : replacement has 3 rows, data has 7`. How do I select only for the conditions but not reduce the size of dataframe needed for replacement?

```
set.seed(111)
level <- c("high","high","high","high","low","low","low")
val <- rnorm(7,35,6)
df <- data.frame(level, val)
df$level <- as.factor(as.character(df$level))

#Creating new column
df$new.val <- df$val

#Conditions
df$new.val <- ifelse(df[df$val > 35 & df$level %in% c("high"),], 0, df$new.val)

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, new.val, value = c(0, 0, 0)) : 
replacement has 3 rows, data has 7


df$new.val <- ifelse(df[df$val > 30 & df$level %in% c("low"),], 0, df$new.val)

level      val    new.val
1  high 36.41132  0
2  high 33.01558  33.01558
3  high 33.13026  33.13026
4  high 21.18593  21.18593
5   low 33.97474  0
6   low 35.84167  0
7   low 26.01544  26.01544
```

Comment: `df$level` is a factor, may be you ment that you want `val` to be greater than 35/30?

Comment: This is typo, you don't need `df[` inside ifelse. Try: `df$new.val <- ifelse(df$val > 35 & df$level %in% c("high"), 0, df$new.val)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following piece of code produces the desirable output.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(111)
level <- c("high","high","high","high","low","low","low")
val <- rnorm(7,35,6)
df <- data.frame(level, val)
df$level <- as.factor(as.character(df$level))

df$new.val <- df$val

    
df %>% 
  mutate(new.val = as.integer(case_when(
    
    val > 35 & level == "high" ~ 0, 
    val > 30 & level == "low" ~ 0,
    TRUE ~ new.val
    
  )))

  level      val new.val
1  high 36.41132       0
2  high 33.01558      33
3  high 33.13026      33
4  high 21.18593      21
5   low 33.97474       0
6   low 35.84167       0
7   low 26.01544      26
```

Comment: "It is not acceptable." - what do you mean?

Comment: i meant that filtering a numeric value for factors is not acceptable. it is a typo

Comment: Since then they edited their post, please edit your answer.